# xcode shell script executable - x flag persistency

Tags: xcode, macos, shell

I have a working OS/X app in Xcode 6. This app checks some input and than executes a shell script.  The shell script is part of the bundle, i.e. it is in the Supporting Files as "script.sh".

Whenever I modify the script, I have to also, through terminal, chmod +x to make it executable for Xcode run to run it.

Is there a way of preserving the "script.sh" executable flag?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Set +x on the source copy of the file.  When it's copied into your app bundle, it should end up with similar permissions.

```
chmod 755 ~/Project/script.sh
```

After this, I was able to edit the script in Xcode and my test app would still run it correctly.

Option 2: Make the +x unnecessary by launching the script indirectly through /bin/bash (or whatever interpreter is appropriate for your script).  e.g.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"script" ofType:@"sh"];
NSTask *task = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash" arguments:@[path]];
[task waitUntilExit];
```